# Return value of ModalDialog is always undefined

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog, return-value, undefined

For some reason, the value returned by the Modal Dialog box is always "undefined".

My Main page (aspx):

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function openWindows () {
    var getval;
    getval = window.showModalDialog('../WebSite/popups/uploader.htm');
    document.getElementById("Input").value = getval;
   }
</script>

<input id="Input" runat="server" />
<input type="button" id="Button1" runat="server" onclick="openWindows()" value="Choose Image"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So in this case, the value of getval is always "undefined"

My Dialog Box (HTML) Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ReturnValues() {
            var objfile = document.getElementById("fileup").value
            document.getElementById("TxtInput").value = objfile
            var vReturnValue = document.getElementById("TxtInput").value;
            window.ReturnValue = vReturnValue;
            window.close();
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Formuploader" method="post" runat="server">
        <input id="TxtInput" type="hidden" runat="server" /><br />
        <button id="btnSaveImage" runat="server" onclick="ReturnValues()">Save Image</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here, ReturnValue does have the required value. But as soon as the ModalDialog closes, the getval variable in the main window becomes undefined.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you return value, do it this way:

```
window.returnValue = vReturnValue;
```

use lowercase `returnValue`, not `ReturnValue`.

also, your modal dialog is not closing. to fix that, change your button to a link.

```
<a href="#" id="btnSaveImage" runat="server" target="_self" onclick="ReturnValue()">
        Save Image</a>
```

Comment: I don't get it.
How is objfile undefined?

Also, the value is getting populated till the the 
    window.ReturnValue = vReturnValue;

Comment: i updated my post. also, take a look at the following article on how to return complex data. http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript/26755-return-value-showmodaldialog.html

Comment: I have another question:

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662592/calling-code-behind-from-javascript

Comment: Ray, please help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367732/gridview-inside-updatepanel-on-modaldialog-not-updating-after-asyncfileupload

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("Input").value = getval;
```

Comment: the problem is at `window.ReturnValue`, it should be `window.returnValue` instead.